# firebase deploy is slow and not responding

Tags: database, deployment, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Running the `deploy` command to a site just makes the Terminal blink as if it was stuck in some heavy operation.

[image]

And nothing would happen. I actually didn't try running with the `--debug` flag.

First thought is that I'm behind a company proxy. So I setup a "pure" connection and it's still not connecting. So what is the problem?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I met the same error too.

Comment: You shoud upgrade to the latest version of the CLI, then run with the `--debug` flag

Answer (score 0):

Open the `firebase-debug.log` file it contains the logs you may find an error in there.

logs similar to this

```
[debug] [2020-09-26T07:53:15.852Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2020-09-26T07:53:15.854Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2020-09-26T07:53:15.855Z] [iam] checking project testproject for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]
[debug] [2020-09-26T07:53:15.861Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2020-09-26T07:53:15.861Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

In my case, it was due to a slow internet connection thus connection could not be established.

Comment: my internet connection is 30mb/s so whats here going wrong same problem

Comment: @AnkurRohilla  Open the 'firebase-debug.log' then check the logs for any errors sometimes the problem is not with the connection speed.

Answer (score -3):

Running `firebase --help` there should be an info popping up if there is an update available.

[image]

If it is **you should update** and then deploy again.

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
firebase deploy
```

If that isn't working, list the projects and check if you are logged in

```
firebase list
firebase login
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with update. I'm able to git push in 2 seconds. Firebase Deploy takes like 3 minutes. What exactly is it doing? It's not as if packages need to be installed. Just push static files and that too takes forever.